# Get URL for Yelp fusion API

Tags: yelp, yelp-fusion-api

I'm attempting to create a url for the Yelp search API endpoint, but can't seem to get the parameters right. I'm pretty new at this, so this is probably a simplistic thing, but I can't find any tutorials on how to create the url.

I've created my API key, but again, the parameters are incorrect.

This is the url I have:

```
https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?accessToken=API_KEY&term=food
```

The JSON output I am recieving is this:

```
{"error": {"code": "VALIDATION_ERROR", "description": "Authorization is a required parameter.", "field": "Authorization", "instance": null}}
```

What is the correct url I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

Your link does not include an access token. To authenticate you must get a private API Key that is automatically generated. That is why the error is showing.

There is no connection between the authorization and the API. I would suggest using [Postman](https://app.getpostman.com/run-collection/6b506a43109229cb2798) to query.

You can set up a bearer token using the token given to you by yelp. This way you can use the Postman tool to query.

Docs:
https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/get_started

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have the authorization value as Bearer  in the headers with your request

Answer (score 0):

I am new to programming but I saw a beautiful error resolution just now and would like to tell you about it.

My error has resolved after I had corrected the spelling of Authorisation as Authorization. (With z in it instead of s).